# Free Form Module in DotNetNuke

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

Actually, I need one customize free form builder module, I have one requirement which has 35 fields in my form (including text boxes, dropdown, radio button, checkboxes, file uploads in my form etc.). I am trying to develop my own module, but its taking a lot of time to develop of 35 fields form using below form development url.

URL: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/module-development

I have following query.

I. Dotnetnuke have the option of customized registration form, but not have a custom form builder for creation form like as my requirement 35 fields form, only registered user will submit this 35 field form.

II. In what situation we have used payment Evoq version, what is the benefit of using this, any customize form builder will available in this payment version.

Comment: There are a lot of modules that can create a form that are available in the DNN store. http://store.dnnsoftware.com/home/product-list/packagetypeid/2?searchtext=forms

Comment: All are purchase module form only, please provide any free one. @VDWWD

Comment: Why? spend a few bucks. Good ones are as low as 30 - 40 dollars...

Answer (score 0):

There are some good free formbuilder modules around. Have a look at OpenForm by Satrabel (https://github.com/sachatrauwaen/openform)